# Can't save image to a variable

Tags: c#, image, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I must be doing something pretty silly... But I've got a WPF application and am using C# to code everything. One thing I'm trying to do is save an image to a variable (mostly so I can create a if statement or whatever to choose different images that can appear).

I did some digging online and it seemed like the only code I really need to do this is:

```
Image pictures = Image.FromFile("");
```

Except this doesn't work... 'FromFile' doesn't seem to be valid code for some reason. Is this a WPF thing and if so, what alternatives are there?

Comment: Are you sure you're using a `System.Drawing.Image` type?

Comment: Yes according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx FromFile should be valid, but for some reason I keep getting the error 'Cannot resolve symbol 'FromFile'.

Comment: Add the `System.Drawing.dll` assembly.

Comment: Oh scratch that just figured out what you mean. Seems to be working now

Comment: Out of curiosity why did i need to add the .dll? System.Drawing is such a basic thing that I've always found it automatically included in all my previous projects? I've only ever needed to reference the assembly.

Comment: You won't usually use `System.Drawing.Image` in a WPF application (as it is WinForms, like all other stuff in the `System.Drawing` namespaces). Loading an image from file in WPF is done by e.g. the [`BitmapImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) class, which takes an `Uri` as constructor parameter, like `var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName));`.

Comment: It would also require some unnecessary conversion code to make a `System.Drawing.Image` show up in WPF's [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) control.